# Python - how to share variables between functions(not using global var)

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

I've a got a code that needs certain variable to be shared as like:

```
def example(arg):
    req = urllib2.Request(r'{}'.format(arg))
    ...
def exampe2(arg):
# i need this func to access req
# i think i can't use req as a global var since the program might need to get imported and it would run from main() (which is again a function)
```

Would really like your help!

Comment: You just add another parameter

Comment: Return it from `example`, pass it to `exampe2`. Or if the former calls the latter, pass it directly.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments; you can do a pass-by-parameter methodology which'd be applied like this:

```
def example2(arg, req):
    ....

def example(arg):
    req = urllib2.Request(r'{}'.format(arg))
    ...
    return example2(..., req)
```

Or you could just as easily integrate the two functions, as you could combine the two `arg` parameters on `example` and `example2`.

Answer (score 0):

this example might help i guess

```
def example1(arg):
    example1.request = "from example1"
    ....

def example2(arg):
    print(example1.request)

example1("arg1")
example2("arg2")

> from example one
```

otherwise you can make request as global and use that request varable inside your example2 function. But all you need to do is execute example1 before example2. Or you can return the request from example1 and assign example1 return value to another variable inside example2.

Comment: This will not run if the function calls are exchanged, because the attribute `example1.request` needs to be instantiated by creating a new function object. Also, is it really the Pythonic to do this? Relying on functions really being objects in Python seems complicated to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it as return values and parameters? This is a feature, since it allows you to keep things as local as possible. If your function needs lots of arguments or gives lots of output, it's often a sign that it can be broken up into multiple functions (a function should ideally do one clearly separated thing and be named as such).

In some cases of course, you want to pass around some data such as configuration options: you might create some new object for this but why not simply a dictionary?

```
def make_request(arg, config):
    req = urllib2.Request(r'{}'.format(arg))
    config['req'] = req
    return config
```

Note that I returned the dict `config`, even though it is not necessary since dicts are mutable in Python. This just makes it clear in the code that I am modifying it. Now we can use the config:

```
def exampe2(arg, config):
    arg = config['arg']
    ...do stuff..
```